# Swift: How to Stop Multiple API Calls

Tags: ios, swift

My app allows users to search for a specific thing after which I make multiple API calls from different sources to get information on what they searched.

I want to add a Stop button so that a user can stop the search if, for example, they have a bad wifi connection and the search is taking too long. I have my API calls in different methods, so I won't know which one is running when the user clicks the Stop button.

Is anyone familiar with a way to stop all functions or even just the API calls running in the app when the user clicks Stop?

Comment: you can use boolean flag variable with initial true value, place all api call inside the if statement checking that flag. On pressing stop, you just set the flag value to false.

Comment: I considered this, but an issue could be that the user searches (bool = true), they press Stop (bool = false), and then they search for something new while the original search is still going making the bool = true and allowing both searches to go through

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

- Create an `Operation` for every API call
- Add `Operation` to `OperationQueue` to start API call
- Call `operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()` to cancel all API call.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Operations, but I'll look into them. Are there any references you would recommend?

Comment: You can also cancel individual operations. It's also possible to write the operation so that if they are doing work in a loop they can check the status of their isCanceled flag and terminate the operation early if they are canceled. There are a couple of good WWDC videos on this very subject.

Answer (score 0):

While using an `OperationQueue` is arguably a better solution, you could also store multiple `URLSessionDataTask`s in an array and use `.cancel()` to stop them all in a loop.

Ex:

```
let task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(...
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(...

let taskArr = [task1, task2]

for task in taskArr {
    task.cancel()
}
```